# Python pptx - Editing excel spreadsheet table (no linked table or outside workbook required)

Tags: python, excel, powerpoint, python-pptx

In PowerPoint, I have Inserted an **Excel Spreadsheet table**, but the "table" only seems to be a graphicframe without a shape type and returns false when I check for a table or chart:

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation('../Template.pptx')
slide = prs.slides[7]
table = slide.shapes[6]
print(table)
>>><pptx.shapes.graphfrm.GraphicFrame object at 0x063BDEB0>
print(table.shape_type)
>>>None
print(table.has_table)
>>>False
print(table.has_chart)
>>>False
```

Any clue how I can actually edit the data inside my table variable?

To recreate this issue, create a slide and add a table through the ribbon **Insert > Table > Excel Spreadsheet**. Then you can modify my script above to call the proper presentation/slide/shape.

---

I will add that when I create a table through Insert > Table > Insert Table... or use `table = slide.shapes.add_table(3,3,x,y,cx,cy)` then `table.has_table` is true. But if the table is created this way, I can't make use of key Excel features like data types and conditional formatting. You can see in the image below, the table formatted with Currency and conditional formatting is much more readable than the one without.

[image: table comparison screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An embedded Excel "table" is not the same sort of thing as a PowerPoint table shape.

The short answer is that there is no API support for editing an embedded Excel range in `python-pptx`.

There are five shape types in PowerPoint: autoshape (regular square, circle, etc.), connector (lines), picture, group-shape, and graphic-frame. A graphic-frame is a "container" for a non-native-PowerPoint shape type, like chart, table, smart-art, and embedded Office object (Excel range in this case).

So the fact that the reported shape type is `GraphicFrame` only narrows it down so far, and not far enough in this case to distinguish between a table and embedded Excel range.

The `GraphicFrame.has_table` property is faithfully doing its job in reporting that the graphic frame does not contain a DrawingML table, although the thing it *does* contain certainly has a tabular appearance.

If you want to work with an embedded Excel range you'd be on your own to manipulate the XML from the `GraphicFrame` down using `lxml` calls. I expect the graphic-frame XML contains a reference to an embedded Excel "file" which could perhaps be opened with `openpyxl` to make changes to it. Still, a pretty advanced bit of coding, mostly complicated by having to reverse-engineer the embedded MS Office object XML semantics and navigating the package structure to obtain the bytes of the embedded Excel "file".

The chart code in `python-pptx` does something similar, because each chart has an embedded Excel file in the `pptx` file that provides the chart data, so that might be somewhere to look for inspiration if you were going to undertake the challenge.

Comment: Are there any plans to improve the API to support embedded tables? As you said, I imagine it's close to how the chart shapes work with embedded Excel files.

Comment: New `python-pptx` features generally appear when someone wants the functionality bad enough to sponsor it. That happens more than you might think, but no one has asked to sponsor this feature so far.